# FullCalendar: Open gcal event in new tab/window

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar, gcal

Is it possible, when feeding a Google Calendar into `FullCalendar`, that when a user clicks on an event in `FullCalendar` that that event is opened in a new tab/window rather than the active tab/window?

I've looked through the `FullCalendar` documentation as well as some searching in this forum and on Google but with no success.  I think my question is pretty simple but I can't seem to find an answer for it.

Answer (score 3):

There is an example in the [gcal demo](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.4/demos/gcal.html).

The code :

```
eventClick: function(event) {
    // opens events in a popup window
    window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
    return false;
},
```

This is an example for opening in a popup window, calling `window.open(event.url, '_blank')` should open a new window/tab.

Comment: Why `return false;`?

Comment: See [the docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/) : fullcalendar's default action is to open this url in the same window. `return false` prevents this from happening.

Comment: Oh for real? I did this to get around that `eventClick: function(event) {`
    `if(event.title) {`
     `window.open(getUrl(event.title),'_blank');`
    `}`
   `},`